# Page numbers also at the top of the Favorites list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

Would it be possible to display the page numbers `1, 2,...,n` not only at the bottom of each page of the Favorites list but also above this list? When I look for an item with `CTRL-F`, I always have to scroll to the bottom to go to the next page, which by default shows the top of the next page. Since the whole page does not fit on my screen, this is very annoying, because you have to do this with every single page.

Comment: If you want to search in them, why don't you do an `infavorites:mine` in the search bar?

Comment: @rene It could be because I have never heard of this possibility to search for it before :) Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: alternatively you could use a SEDE query as I offered in my [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283124/158100)